# boostrap customize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with Bootstrap, how can you customize the carousel?

Any suggestions?

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/

Comment: Out of the box, they are only horizontal.  If you want to make it vertical you're going to have to hack it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.active.carousel-item-right, .carousel-item-next {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
            transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}
.active.carousel-item-left, .carousel-item-prev {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
            transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}
```

... should do. See it in action:

```css
.carousel-item.active.carousel-item-right, 
.carousel-item.carousel-item-next {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
            transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}
.carousel-item.active.carousel-item-left, 
.carousel-item.carousel-item-prev {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
            transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" data-src="holder.js/800x400?auto=yes&amp;bg=777&amp;fg=555&amp;text=First slide" alt="First slide [800x400]" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_15fc214ab4b%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23555%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_15fc214ab4b%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22285.9296875%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3EFirst%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" data-holder-rendered="true">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" data-src="holder.js/800x400?auto=yes&amp;bg=666&amp;fg=444&amp;text=Second slide" alt="Second slide [800x400]" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_15fc214ab4f%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23444%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_15fc214ab4f%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23666%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22247.3203125%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3ESecond%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" data-holder-rendered="true">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" data-src="holder.js/800x400?auto=yes&amp;bg=555&amp;fg=333&amp;text=Third slide" alt="Third slide [800x400]" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_15fc214ab52%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23333%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_15fc214ab52%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23555%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22277.0078125%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3EThird%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" data-holder-rendered="true">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Note: In the example, I had to make the selectors stronger, by adding `.carousel-item` to them, but that's only because bootstrap.css gets loaded after the snippet CSS, (which I think is a bug and it's clearly wrong). In real life, the code on top will suffice, as long as you it load after `bootstrap(.min).css`

Comment: I have been looking for days for a solution, and sifted through SO many that did not work. This worked PERFECTLY. Thank you kind, css master/internet stranger.